# Scala, ZIO - how to return custom error from ZIO

Tags: scala, either, zio, tapir

I have a simple code which using `tapir` `sttp.client3.json._`:

```
def method(...): Task[MyResponse] = 
   someLogic().response(asJson[MyResponse]).flatMap(res => ZIO.fromEither(res.body))
```

But now I want to add here some logic to use custom errors when `asJson[MyResponse]` failed.
I created my error hierarchy:

```
sealed trait MyError extends Throwable
case class MyFirstError (msg: String) extends MyError 
case class MySecondError (msg: String) extends MyError
```

And I changed `Task` to `IO[MyError, MyResponse]`, but I have no idea how should I return errors when they appeared and return same correct `MyResponse` when everything is ok.
I tried smth like this:

```
def method(...): IO[MyError, MyResponse] = 
       someLogic().response(asJson[MyResponse]).flatMap{ res =>
         res.code match {
           case StatusCode.BadRequest => ZIO.fail(MyFristError("my error"))
           case StatusCode.Forbidden => ZIO.fail(MySecondError("my other error"))
           case _ => ZIO.fromEither(res.body).orDie
         }
       }
```

I got an error here `Required IO[MyError, MyResponse], Found ZIO[Any, Throwable, MyResponse]`
How should I fix this code to return my custom errors depend on the status code and correct response when everything is ok?

Comment: I think this `someLogic().response(asJson[MyResponse])` is already setting error channel to `Throwable` - when you `flatMap` you calculate a common time between error channel before and the one in `flatMap` getting `Throwable`. You'd have to `mapError` from `Throwable` to `MyError` (or die) before `flatMap`ping the response.

Comment: This is what I need - map error to my custom type, depends on te response status code. But I'm not sure how should I do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into this issue on the "catch-all" case:

```scala
  case _ => ZIO.fromEither(res.body).orDie
```

The `fromEither` is returning some `IO[E, A]` my assumption is that the `E` is where you're running into the `Throwable`. Explicity declaring the types should fix it: `fromEither[MyError, MyResponse]`.

If adding the types explicity isn't possible, then instead of using `orDie`, you could use `refineOrDie { case e: MyError => e }`.

Comment: So, how could I check response code and decide about specific error here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you are checking the response code with: `res.code match`. 
The `_` case is all other response codes other than the 2 you specified (`BadRequest` and `Forbidden`). 
If you want to specify to a specific error, then I would "wrap" it into another MyError definition (see `UnexpectedResponseCode` in [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74709443/15456492))

Answer (score 0):

The signature defines what kind of errors your method can produce. `orDie` terminates the fiber (with any `Throwable`, not necessarily `MyError`) so you can

1. either catchall all exceptions and map to your trait:

```
sealed trait MyError extends Throwable
case class MyFirstError (msg: String) extends MyError 
case class MySecondError (msg: String) extends MyError 
case class UnexpectedResponseCode(msg: String) extends MyError
```

```
def method(...): IO[MyError, MyResponse] = 
  someLogic().response(asJson[MyResponse]).flatMap{ res =>
    res.code match {
      case StatusCode.BadRequest => ZIO.fail(MyFristError("my error"))
      case StatusCode.Forbidden => ZIO.fail(MySecondError("my other error"))
      case unexpectedResponseCode => ZIO.fail(UnexpectedResponseCode(s"I.I. Rabi> Who ordered that '$unexpectedResponseCode'?")
    }
  }
}
```

2. Or make the signature more general, i.e.

```
def method(...): Task[MyResponse] // AKA IO[Throwable, MyResponse]
```